# How to change the Text on the image?

Tags: html, photoshop

Below is the image, where I have text on the image. I am wondering on how the text on the Image can be changed. Actually someone else wrote the code and I am not getting. Please Help me out Friends.
[image]

And this is the code which is working on this.

```
    <div class="TabsV">
        <div id="Tab0" class="TabV Selected" style="height: 86px;">
            <a style="background-position: -8px -12px; padding-bottom: 70px;" href="javascript: SelectTab(0)"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="Tab1" class="TabV" style="height: 116px;">
            <a style="background-position: -40px 0px; padding-bottom: 100px;" href="javascript: SelectTab(1)"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="TabVEmpty" style="height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Dude there is no text...

Comment: Can you post the source? Are you sure this is the part? And are you sure no othe scripts are referring to the tabs?

Comment: @Alex Ok, But How the image is working with the help of JavaScript???

Comment: The image is probably defined by some style rules (CSS). Check your stylesheets for 'Tab'.

Comment: @Alex Yes, Got It. Image is defined by CSS. Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not! You must edit those image files in an image editor. The text from the tabs isn't coded in the html code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the text is part of the image.

So you need to edit the actual images and change the text there.

If you look at the stylesheet used in that page you will find something similar to

```
.TabV a{
   /*in here you will see the url of the image being used
   background:...
   or background-image: url('..');
   */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the image itself contains text and it is applied via the TabV class - notice how the background-position coordinates changes between one tab and the other.

If you look in your CSS file, you should see something like:

```
.TabV 
{
    background-image: url(...)
}
```

What you need to do, therefore, is to manipulate the existing image used as background and add the text you want to that image. Then you need to modify the background-position of the corresponding anchor element. One way to do that with jQuery is:

```
$('#Tab0').attr("background-position","-16px 20px;"); //-16px and 20px are just an example
```

Where `#Tab0` is the css selector for the first tab. #Tab1 would be the css selector for the second tab... `"#<something>"` maps to `id="<something>"` in the html markup.

The technique itself is called CSS sprites. You can read more about this technique [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

Comment: So, This is correct explanation. Which I was needed. 
You are right. The Single image itself contains all the text. And I have to move in to right position.
Thanks a lot.. :-)